# Creating a new column value based on calculating existing column value in a data frame

Tags: pandas, ipython, dataframe

I have a data frame which consists of a column named as ' Lnc ' which is of type integer , and I want to create another column value in the same data frame named Log_Lnc which is log base2 value of the column Lnc.
 Would really appreciate if I could get help for the same .

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`np.log2`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.log2.html):

```
In [17]:
df = pd.DataFrame({'Lnc':np.arange(5)})
df['LogLnc'] = np.log2(df['Lnc'])
df

Out[17]:
   Lnc    LogLnc
0    0      -inf
1    1  0.000000
2    2  1.000000
3    3  1.584963
4    4  2.000000
```

Comment: Thank you Ed , for the help , really appreciate that 
I had just one more issue in pandas :- 

I have a column name 'target_date' and i have a condition that - if mdy(9,24,2007)<=(target_date) and (target_date)<mdy(9,22,2008) then , I want to replace value of column - 'Season' = 2007

Would really appreciate if you could help me with that

Comment: IIUC then you can do `df.loc[(df['target_date']>= '2007-09-24') & (df['target_date'] < '2008-09-22'),'Season'] = 2007` should work, this uses 2 boolean conditions and ands them using `&`, as we are using the array `&` operator you have to enclose the conditions with `()` due to operator precedence, we use `loc` to mask the rows of interest